# What are the Linux (64-bit) repositories can I use to get HAProxy 1.4.19?

Tags: debian, haproxy, debian-squeeze

What are the Linux (64-bit) repositories can I use to get HAProxy 1.4.19?

I keep getting 1.4.8 as the latest version for Debian Squeeze AMD64. There are a lot of fixes on the latest version and I want to get it.

I have the following repositories in my sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.hk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.hk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
```

Does always getting 1.4.8 only mean anything? Could it mean that there are compatibility issues with the latest version? I looked thru the documentation but I didn't see any exceptions with regard to app-OS-version compatibility.

I'm a Linux newbie and still have a lot of catching up to do. Please excuse my questions. :)

I'd appreciate any advice.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does always getting 1.4.8 only mean anything?

That is normal for a **stable** version of Debian, and most Linux distributions.  When a version is released the packages versions are basically fixed, and no upgrades happen aside from backported security patches.

> What are the Linux repositories can I use to get...

As far as I can tell from doing some searching, there are none.  You are going to need to build from source or build your own package.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, as of right now, for you to get a Debian package newer than 1.4.15 from any repo. It is possible, of course, that someone has manually packaged it, but that would be difficult to find. See the [package search results](http://packages.debian.org/haproxy).

You could backport 1.4.15 from Sid to Squeeze. This isn't terribly difficult, but can be confusing if you haven't done it before. See [this FAQ](http://wooledge.org/~greg/sidfaq.html#11) for more info.